# Realm - Column Type is not vaid

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I am using realm in my current application and I thought of an updating my app. Now, this process takes `migrating of tables` and new entities and schema if you are using database in the app to save some values.

My issue here is that I am having some issues with migration because theres is not good documentation for Realm Migration yet and I am getting couple of errors which includes the `error : Column type not valid`.

**This is my approach towards migrating :**

*First, this is how the realm configuration looks like :*

```
public class RealmHelper implements RealmMigration {

    public static final long SCHEMA_VERSION = 2; // This was the 2nd schema.
    public static final String REALM_NAME = "john.example";

    public static RealmConfiguration getRealmConfig(Context context) {
        return new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name(REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
    }
}
```

*Second, this is the Migration class : This is where the issue is.*

```
    public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

        @Override
            public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
              if(version == 2){
                // Issue is here. Notice the "otherModel". That is an entity in the SampleClass table.
                Table sampleTable = realm.getTable(SampleClass.class);
                sampleTable.addColumn(ColumnType.TABLE, "otherModel", true); 

               }
            }
        }
```

*Last, the SampleClass, which is a wrapper for the actual Data model.*

```
public class SampleClass extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("somename")
    private OtherModel otherModel;


    public OtherModel getOtherModel() {
        return otherModel;
    }

    public void setOtherModel(OtherModel otherModel) {
        this.otherModel = otherModel;
    }

}
```

Based on the current scenario, I am getting an error here where it says that the ColumnType is not valid.

```
Table sampleTable = realm.getTable(SampleClass.class);
sampleTable.addColumn(ColumnType.TABLE, "otherModel", true);
```

I am not sure what exactly can be the column type if its just an Object in the Wrapper Model.

I will really appreciate any kind of help here.. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a reference to another RealmObject, it is called a Link:

```
sampleTable.addColumn(ColumnType.LINK, "otherModel", realm.getTable(OtherModel.class);
```

You can also see an example of it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java#L89-L89 except this references a RealmList instead of a RealmObject

Comment: Got it .. thanks for the explanation.. Really helpful. And yes, ColumnType.LINK was something I wasn't able to find on the docs. Thank you.. :)